# Confusing type hint warning in Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pycharm

Can anyone explain why Pycharm makes a type warning here?

```
import numpy as np

def test(arr: np.ndarray) -> tuple:
    to_return = np.where((arr > 0.1) & (arr < 0.9))
    return to_return  # marks the text with "Expected type 'tuple', got 'ndarray' instead"


a = np.random.rand(10, 10)

res = test(a)


print(type(res))  #<class 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Does `np.nonzero(...)` instead of `where` give the same warning?  They do the same thing, but the preferred use for `where` is the 3 argument case, which would return an array.  `nonzero` unambiguously returns a tuple.

Comment: np.nonzero() does fine ! Thanks